# sql date format convert from 2013-04-01 00:00:00.000 to 2013-04-01 12:00:00

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following date in the my sql table

```
2013-04-01 00:00:00.000
2013-06-19 15:57:10.357
2013-06-19 15:57:10.370
2013-06-19 15:57:10.383
2013-06-19 15:57:10.397
2013-04-01 00:00:00.000
2013-04-01 00:00:00.000
2013-04-01 00:00:00.000
2013-06-19 15:57:10.410
```

My question is:

How do i make it to `2013-04-01 12:00:00` to the one that date is `2013-04-01 00:00:00.000`

Comment: Add 12 hours to turn it to noon from midnight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your source data *always* has a time of midnight (which I doubt, otherwise the time wouldn't be important), adding 12 hours could result in an incorrect date.

You can do it by taking parts from two different format codes:

120 - ODBC canonical - `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss`(24h)

109 - Default + milliseconds - `mon dd yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmmAM` (or `PM`)

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(10),@date,120) + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(char(20),@date,109),12,9)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add 12 hours.  And the easiest way to do that is to add 0.5:

```
select mydate + 0.5;
```

Your sample code doesn't really make sense.  First, it is working on the current date value, rather than a column in the data.  Also, it is missing a length on the first argument.  *Always* include length when specifying a character data type.

Comment: that will not work and what if i have datetime `2013-08-25 12:30:00.000` ? it will add another `.5` to it? which i am not looking for that, i want only to the one that has `2013-04-01 00:00:00.000`

Comment: @AbuHamzah . . . It seems that you have not specified your question clearly.  Can you revise the question to clarify what you really mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
select CONVERT(varchar(30),getdate(),100)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a whole lot of styles for you

```
SELECT

    GETDATE() AS GetDate,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),0) AS '0',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),100) AS '100',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),1) AS '1',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),101) AS '101',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),7) AS '7',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),107) AS '107',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),108) AS '108',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),108) AS '108',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),10) AS '10',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),110) AS '110',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),12) AS '12',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112) AS '112',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),14) AS '14',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),114) AS '114'
```